# Best practice for nodejs app deployment to Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, deployment, azure-functions

Recently I started to work on Nodejs project, and we are using Azure Functions for this. I'm curios about app deployment to Azure.

First I tried to find a serverless plugin to install dependency packages during deployment process. Couldn't find an easy way to do this.

After some googling and reading this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps) I figured out that best practice is to install packages on build step, and deploy already generated node_modules.

> Deploying the node_modules directory as part of your application increases the size of the deployment. ... however, it does guarantee that the versions of the modules used in production are the same as the modules used in development.

So I tried to follow this, and deploy small app with dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "azure-function-express": "^1.3.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
  "express": "^4.16.2",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
  "cors": "^2.8.4"
}
```

Zip file to deploy was about 709 KB. It deployed successfully. But when I added one more package (mongoose)

```
"dependencies": {
  "azure-function-express": "^1.3.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
  "express": "^4.16.2",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "mongoose": "^5.0.11"
}
```

The size of zip became 2.83 mb and deployment hangs with message "Uploading function: ...", function not deployed, and no logs.

It hangs... I'm not sure what the precise reason is, but it doesn't work even with few packages, what if I add more big packages?

I kindly ask your advice how you solve such kind of issues, and which method best works for you to build and deploy Nodejs Azure Functions. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried funcpack (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack)? It may be the plugin you're looking for!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is to use webpack to bundle a lot of packages into one file. And then it's easy and fast to deploy. If you use `serverless` framework there is a package [serverless-webpack](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) to do the job.

Comment: Did you eneded up including node_modules in your zip?

Comment: No, including node_modules just did't work if I had even few packages, it was hanging. So we were using webpack to bundle all files into one and this way it worked (as I described in answer. Not sure maybe today there is some better approach

Comment: When you say "using webpack to bundle all files into one" you mean you bundled third party dependencies (node pacakges) too?

Comment: Regarding another approach I came across [Using Node.js Modules with Azure applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps) and [startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure.markdown](https://github.com/woloski/nodeonazure-blog/blob/master/articles/startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure.markdown) which explains how to install packages on the app at deployment time. I am yet to try it though.

Comment: Well, you can give it a try. So far I've found using single file bundled with webpack is the most convenient way. You have to consider packages' versions, native modules, deployment time, etc. With bundling it's much simpler. However you can try other options, it's a way to gain experience )