# Failed to deploy web package to App Service "there is not enough space on the disk"

Tags: node.js, git, azure, deployment, autodesk-forge

Trying to deploy a node.js project on microsoft azure from my git repository, however after taking around an hour to build I get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig4sr.png) during the deployment phase, any ideas what could be causing this?

got a feeling it could be to do with the "npm install" command being ran on startup, having all those modules being installed at once probably makes it hit the file size limit of something. If this is the case tho, any advice on how to shrink my project size?

Git project: https://github.com/JonathanAdamsONE/onedeployment

Comment: You can refer to [Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098456/error-error-failed-to-deploy-web-package-to-app-service-bad-request-code-40), [Azure App Service - What is taking my disk space for my Azure Web App ?](https://puneet-gupta.github.io/puneetgupta/2017/06/06/azure-app-service-what-is-taking-my-disk-space-for-my-azure-web-app/) and [Best practice for nodejs app deployment to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860724/best-practice-for-nodejs-app-deployment-to-azure?rq=1)

Comment: What App Service Plan tier did you allocate for the service?

Comment: using azure for free, and I've got pro github, reckon its because I need to up the space on azure?